# marker click on map display modal window angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, typescript, google-maps-api-3

On marker click want to display a modal window.

My code:

```
      google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker,'click', (marker)=> {

        openModal();

      });


    openModal() {
  this.modalService.open(content).result.then((result) => {
    this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
  }, (reason) => {
    this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
  });
```

I tried including open method in  addeventListener , saying content id is defined. my starting  point  for modal window is marker click.

HTML CODE

```
    <h4>{{title}}</h4>

<div id="dvMap"   style="width:900px;height:600px;"></div>
<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="c('Close click')">Close</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Tried like this also

```
<div id="dvMap" (click)="openModal()"  style="width:900px;height:600px;"></div>
```

after adding this getting error as "openModal is not defined".

http://plnkr.co/edit/LITQXFzZE7ETnTSH9nSP?p=preview  Used this plunkr code as refrence and using ng-bootstrap.